# Get junk instead of string in toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I have a small metod. It's get string with eng characters and return rus characters string (transliteration); But it's something wrong with it. I have no idea what. It's returned not string on Russian, but some junk like "[C@4057db80";

```
public String getRussianSting(String engString) {
    char[] engCharString = engString.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] rusCharString = new char[30];

    for (int i = 0; i <= engCharString.length - 1; i++) {
        if (engCharString[i] == ' ')
            continue;

        if (i + 1 <= engCharString.length - 1) {
            if (engCharString[i] == 'c' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'h') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'ч';
                i++;
                continue;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 's' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'h') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'ш';
                i++;
                continue;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 't' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'z') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'ц';
                i++;
                continue;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 'y' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'i') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'ы';
                i++;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 'y' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'e') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'э';
                i++;
                continue;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 'y' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'u') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'ю';
                i++;
                continue;

            } else if (engCharString[i] == 'y' && engCharString[i + 1] == 'a') {
                rusCharString[i] = 'я';
                i++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        switch (engCharString[i]) {
            case 'a':
                rusCharString[i] = 'а';
                break;
            case 'b':
                rusCharString[i] = 'б';
                break;
            case 'v':
                rusCharString[i] = 'в';
                break;
            case 'g':
                rusCharString[i] = 'г';
                break;
            case 'd':
                rusCharString[i] = 'д';
                break;
            case 'e':
                rusCharString[i] = 'е';
                break;
            case 'j':
                rusCharString[i] = 'ж';
                break;
            case 'z':
                rusCharString[i] = 'з';
                break;
            case 'i':
                rusCharString[i] = 'и';
                break;
            case 'k':
                rusCharString[i] = 'к';
                break;
            case 'l':
                rusCharString[i] = 'л';
                break;
            case 'm':
                rusCharString[i] = 'м';
                break;
            case 'n':
                rusCharString[i] = 'н';
                break;
            case 'o':
                rusCharString[i] = 'о';
                break;
            case 'p':
                rusCharString[i] = 'п';
                break;
            case 'r':
                rusCharString[i] = 'р';
                break;
            case 's':
                rusCharString[i] = 'с';
                break;
            case 't':
                rusCharString[i] = 'т';
                break;
            case 'u':
                rusCharString[i] = 'у';
                break;
            case 'f':
                rusCharString[i] = 'ф';
                break;
            case 'h':
                rusCharString[i] = 'х';
                break;
            case '\'':
                rusCharString[i] = 'ь';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return rusCharString.toString();
}
```

Comment: Try `return new String(rusCharString);`

Comment: @Supericy turn that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return rusCharString.toString();
```

will return the String showing the object representation of the array. That is one major reason `char[]` is used for sensitive data instead of String.

**try:**

```
return new String(rusCharString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use the `toString` of an array, it will use the one that it inherits from `Object` class.

If you want to get a proper `toString` of an array, use `java.util.Arrays.toString(rusCharString)`. The junk that you see is the hash code of that array.

If you want to print the hash code separately, use `rusCharArray.hashCode()`

Comment: Using `new String(char[])` would be faster and simpler.